# No method 'configuration' for Configuration in Generator Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm baffled with this one. I wrote a gem recently that adds a generator to Rails projects. I'm trying to add configuration to the gem to set defaults for the generator. However, when I try to reference the module's configuration method from the generator, I get a `no method 'configuration'` error.

Here is the relevant code:

**componentize.rb**

```
require 'rails'
require "componentize/engine"
require "componentize/version"
require "componentize/configuration"

module Componentize
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end

  def self.reset
    @configuration = Configuration.new
  end
end
```

**componentize/configuration.rb**

```
module Componentize
  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :extension, :view_partial_dir, :inline_style_partial_dir, :block_style_partial_dir, :import_file

    def initialize
      @extension = 'erb'
      @view_partial_dir = 'application'
      @inline_style_partial_dir = 'blocks'
      @block_style_partial_dir = 'sections'
      @import_file = 'base.scss'
    end
  end
end
```

**componentize/component_generator.rb**

```
require 'rails/generators/named_base'

module Componentize
  class ComponentGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
    # Componentize.configuration will error here.
  end
end
```

And for what it's worth, if I `puts Componentize.configuration.extension` inside of my test, it `puts 'erb'` just like it should, so I know that the configuration method is available somewhere.

**spec/lib/generators/componentize/component_spec.rb**

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'generator_spec'
require 'generators/componentize/component_generator'

describe Componentize::ComponentGenerator, type: :generator do
  destination File.expand_path('../tmp', __FILE__)
  arguments %w(test-component)

  before :all do
    prepare_destination
    create_tmp_dirs_and_files
    show_me_componentize
    run_generator
  end

  it "creates a view file" do
    assert_file "app/views/application/_test_component.html.erb"
  end

  it "creates an scss file" do
    assert_file "app/assets/stylesheets/blocks/_test_component.scss"
  end

  it "finds a base.scss file" do
    assert_file "app/assets/stylesheets/base.scss"
  end

  private

  def create_tmp_dirs_and_files
    FileUtils.mkdir_p('spec/lib/generators/tmp/app/assets/stylesheets')
    FileUtils.touch('spec/lib/generators/tmp/app/assets/stylesheets/base.scss')
  end

  def show_me_componentize
    puts Componentize.configuration.extension # works just fine
  end
end
```

Anyone understand why I get a `no method 'configuration'` error?

**EDIT 1**

Let's throw a wrench in this. Went ahead and finished writing out all the code that would use the configuration, and it all passes when I run the tests. Thus, `Componentize.configuration.extension` and any of the other `attr_accessors` in the `Configuration` class work correctly when tests run. The failure I am getting is when trying to run the gem's generator in a Rails project, when I remove the configuration, the generator runs, when I have the configuration present, it gives the no method error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off, I feel this is a bit beyond my knowledge, but I'll just throw a wild guess.

```
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end
```

Maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that both of those two blocks will create a configuration method under the same namespace?

Also, I'm trying to test here running pure ruby, with some minor changes, and I get no errors:

```
module Componentize
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end

  def self.reset
    @configuration = Configuration.new
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :extension

    def initialize
      @extension = 'erb'
    end
  end

  class ComponentGenerator # < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
    @default_extension = Componentize.configuration.extension # failure here
    # More code
  end

  ComponentGenerator.new
end
```

Comment: For the record, your first hunch is unlikely to be the issue, I have used and have seen this pattern before. Here's an example: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block I have these classes in separate files, so I will update my example to reflect that in case I am missing an include/require some where.